# Failed To Revoke Role From A User

Tags: sql, oracle, privileges

From Oracle Sql Developer, I ran the `GRANT MyRole TO MyUser;` command to grand MyRole to MyUser, then I ran `REVOKE MyRole FROM MyUser;` command to revoke MyRole from MyUser but got the error:

```
Error starting at line 50 in command:
REVOKE MyRole FROM MyUser
Error report:
SQL Error: ORA-01932: ADMIN option not granted for role 'MyRole'
01932. 00000 -  "ADMIN option not granted for role '%s'"
*Cause:    The operation requires the admin option on the role.
*Action:   Obtain the grant option and re-try.
```

Please, tell me what should I do to revoke MyRole from MyUser.

Comment: Only the database owner can revoke a role. See here: http://docs.oracle.com/javadb/10.6.1.0/ref/rrefsqljrevoke.html

Comment: @DavidBrabant - not true.  It's just a matter of having the right level of privilege.  Please re-read the document you linked.  Or even better read the SQL reference rather than Java documentation (see my answer)

Answer (score 3):

The [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/statements_9020.htm#SQLRF55180) is as clear as the error message:

> "To revoke a role, you must have been granted the role with the ADMIN OPTION."

That means your user must be granted the role like this:

```
grant myrole to you WITH ADMIN OPTION ;
```

Of course, you also need that to *grant* the role ...

```
SQL> conn db_admin/db_admin
Connected.
SQL> create role myrole;

Role created.

SQL> grant myrole to a; 

Grant succeeded.

SQL> conn a/a
Connected.
SQL> grant myrole to b;
grant myrole to b
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01932: ADMIN option not granted for role 'MYROLE'

SQL> conn db_admin/db_admin
Connected.
SQL> grant myrole to a with admin option;

Grant succeeded.

SQL> conn a/a
Connected.
SQL> grant myrole to b;

Grant succeeded.

SQL> revoke myrole from b;

Revoke succeeded.

SQL>
```

Comment: what should I do to revoke `myrole` from `a`. When I login with `a` user and re-run `GRANT myrole TO a with admin option;` (replaced with my real role and user), the same error occured.

Comment: Resolved.Login as sys and just run `REVOKE MyRole FROM MyUser;`